# How to sort a pandas data frame by value counts of a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to sort the following pandas data frame by the result of  `df['user_id'].value_counts()`.

```
import pandas as pd
n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.Index(range(1, n+1), name='gridimage_id'))
df['user_id'] = 2
df['has_term'] = True
df.iloc[:10, 0] = 1
```

The sort should be stable, meaning that whilst user 2's rows would come before user 1's rows, the user 2's rows and user 1's rows would be in the original order.

I was thinking about using `df.groupby`, merging `df['user_id'].value_counts()` with the data frame, and also converting `df['user_id']` to ordered categorical data. However, none of these approaches seemed particularly elegant.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### `transform` and `argsort`

Use `kind='mergesort'` for stability

```
df.iloc[df.groupby('user_id').user_id.transform('size').argsort(kind='mergesort')]
```

---

### `factorize`, `bincount`, and `argsort`

Use `kind='mergesort'` for stability

```
i, r = pd.factorize(df['user_id'])
a = np.argsort(np.bincount(i)[i], kind='mergesort')
df.iloc[a]
```

---

### Response to Comments

> Thank you @piRSquared. Is it possible to reverse the sort order, though? value_counts is in descending order. In the example, user 2 has 90 rows and user 1 has 10 rows. I'd like user 2's rows to come first. Unfortunately, Series.argsort ignores the order kwarg. – Iain Dillingham 4 mins ago

#### Quick and Dirty

Make the counts negative

```
df.iloc[df.groupby('user_id').user_id.transform('size').mul(-1).argsort(kind='mergesort')]
```

Or

```
i, r = pd.factorize(df['user_id'])
a = np.argsort(-np.bincount(i)[i], kind='mergesort')
df.iloc[a]
```

Comment: Thank you @piRSquared. Is it possible to reverse the sort order, though? `value_counts` is in descending order. In the example, user 2 has 90 rows and user 1 has 10 rows. I'd like user 2's rows to come first. Unfortunately, `Series.argsort` ignores the `order` kwarg.

Comment: The quick and dirty way is to make the results of `np.bincount(i)[i]` negative. `-np.bincount(i)[i]`.  I'm looking for a more aesthetically pleasing solution.